# How to sort an array of pointers in alphabetical order, and then use qsort?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, qsort

I am trying to write a function in which I sort the pointers inside of `wptrs`, an array of pointers to strings in another array. I am challenging myself not to use string.h for this exercise, as I want to understand how a sorting algorithm could work in C. I am using `qsort()`, however, but I am trying to write a comparison function for it called `mycharptrcompare()`.

I have looked at how `strcmp()` works, and I have tried to mimic that with `mycharptrcompare()`. However, I notice the difference that `strcmp()` expects a char*, while the `mycharptrcompare()` function expects a char**. I've written a method called `dumpwptrs` to show me the contents and how they are organized within `wptrs`. Thus far, I have the following code:

**UPDATE:**

I have also tried:

```
int mycharptrcompare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
  //Need to convert a void * to a more specific type to dereference
  const char *aPtr = a;
  const char *bPtr = b;
  const char **pa = &aPtr;
  const char **pb = &bPtr;

  while (*pa && *pa == *pb) {
    pa++;
    pb++;
  }
  return *pa - *pb;
}
```

and my output I got was:

(null)

jumps

world

is

dog

blue

Which is still incorrect, because my list should be sorted in alphabetical order, and the first input (the word "hello"), has not been read in.

Comment: The second argument passed to `qsort` is `sizeof(wptrs)` and this is very unlikely to be the number of elements in the array. It is very unclear what you are doing in the comparator function provided for `qsort`. This is supposed to provide comparison information for `qsort` and I don't see how implementing your own sort within that is relevant, or helpful. If the sort is on string values, all you need to do is return the comparison value from `strcmp()`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you, I think I see my error for sure with using sizeof(wptrs). Could I use an integer value insead of this, or would I have to use something of type size_t?

Comment: Please see my example answer.

Comment: @WeatherVane The comparator function I am trying to write needs to sort the array of pointers, not the array itself. The array of pointers I have is `wptrs`, which is why I am not using `strcmp()`

Comment: My example sorts the pointers. You can't sort the array, because the string literals are of differnt lengths and are read-only. It is the array of pointers which is sorted. That's why the double-star: the comparator function is passed the address of the array elements, not what they in turn point to.

Answer (score 1):

FYI here is an example use of `qsort()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int cmp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const char **pa = a;
    const char **pb = b;
    return strcmp(*pa, *pb);
}

int main(void)
{
    char *wptrs[] = { "hello", "jumps", "world", "is", "dog", "blue" };
    size_t len = sizeof wptrs / sizeof wptrs[0];
    qsort(wptrs, len, sizeof wptrs[0], cmp);

    for(size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", wptrs[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
blue
dog
hello
is
jumps
world
```

Comment: I could have used `int` not `size_t` for the small number of elements, but if `size_t` can hold a larger value than `int` (e.g. 64 bits vs 32 bits) there will be a compiler warning.

Comment: I used your advice (very helpful), I also made an update to the question. I am getting an implicit declaration error.

Comment: You are getting errors because you have written code different to this example.

Comment: Yes, I understand that now. I am just trying to use my own version of strcmp() instead of the standard one. I'll look into that, and hopefully if I fix it, that will resolve my errors.

Comment: `return mystrcmp(*pa, *pb);` passes `char` values to `mystrcmp`, not `char*` pointers.

Comment: Hi @WeatherVane, would you be able to look at my update? I feel like I am getting close but am still missing something. I am continuing to work on it.

Comment: I tried to use your exact solution with strcmp(), but I get the following error: **initializing 'const char **' with an expression of
      type 'const void *' discards qualifiers**

Comment: Was that a warning or an error? `const char **pa = (const char **)a;`